# Automatically disallowing large indentations

Tags: python, static-analysis

In our code base, I often find functions formatted in the following way:

```
some_function_with_a_very_long_name(parameter_a,
                                    parameter_b,
                                    parameter_c)
```

This moves a lot of information to the right side of the screen and less readable than the cleaner alternative:

```
some_function_with_a_very_long_name(
    parameter_a,
    parameter_b,
    parameter_c,
)
```

This could be detected by checking that the number of indentations in any given line is at most one indentation level greater than the line before.

Is there any linting rule (in Flake8, SonarQube or similar) that I can use to automatically check that this is done properly in our CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html) automatically wraps parameters, but I guess you would prefer something that only checks the indentations?

Comment: This is more than just this one rule, but it looks very promising. I will probably end up using black if there's no more minimal solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I just wrote, it returns a list of all (should be all) blocks where there is overindentation like here (also the line of code (starting at line 1)):

```py
some_function_with_a_very_long_name(parameter_a,
                                    parameter_b,
                                    parameter_c)
```

Then you can iterate over that list to print out all those cases
Code:

```py
def find_over_indentations(file_name, level_depth, search_possible=True):
    def count_spaces_before(lst):
        counter = 0
        for item in lst:
            if item == '':
                counter += 1
                counter = counter
            else:
                break
        return counter

    faulty_blocks = list()
    faulty_block = ''
    previous_line = ''
    caution = False
    previous_indentation_level = 0

    with open(file_name) as file:
        for index, line in enumerate(file):
            split_by_space = line.split(' ')
            spaces_before = count_spaces_before(split_by_space)
            current_indentation_level = spaces_before // level_depth
            possible_fault = spaces_before % level_depth if search_possible else 0
            if ((current_indentation_level - previous_indentation_level > 1 or possible_fault != 0)
                    and faulty_block == ''):
                caution = True
                faulty_block += str(index) + ' ' + previous_line
                faulty_block += str(index + 1) + ' ' + line
            elif caution and current_indentation_level == previous_indentation_level:
                faulty_block += str(index + 1) + ' ' + line
            else:
                if faulty_block != '':
                    faulty_blocks.append(faulty_block)
                    faulty_block = ''
                caution = False
            previous_indentation_level = current_indentation_level
            previous_line = line
    if faulty_block != '':
        faulty_blocks.append(faulty_block)

    return faulty_blocks


if __name__ == '__main__':
    over_indents = find_over_indentations('test.py', 4)
    for over_indented in over_indents:
        print(over_indented)
```

Basically you can just use this code (just replace the file name with whatever file you need) and it should print out all those lines where is such issues (it will also show the "starting" line for example in the above case this will also get printed: `some_function_with_a_very_long_name(parameter_a,`), also possible to toggle possible faults (default is true) and it basically checks if there are indents outside of the level depth for example an extra space or two, level depth argument is how deep is level for example usually it is 4 spaces (tab)

EDIT1: there was a slight issue with the first if statement in a case when there was a possible fault (out of indention depth) where it run that if statement twice so I added a condition so that that if statement runs only if there is nothing appended to the faulty_block. (also this introduces an interesting situation in the current where it is formatted correctly as per indentation level but it would be appended to the list if this function run on this file, that is why it shows line number and previous line so that human can go and check them manually but they don't have to look all over the file)

Comment: edited answer to include a more complete code

Comment: also just in case I just want to tell you not to delete the question if this resolved your issue since this answer may help future readers (also marking this as accepted will help future readers and it will be possible to mark other questions as duplicates with this one)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I would rather not introduce more custom code into the build pipeline to avoid having to maintain it, but this would indeed do it. I will not remove the question, don't worry!